# Selecting an array in the MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
{
"_id": "4f609932615a935c18r000000",
"members": [
    {
        "user_name": "john1",
        "role": "user",
        "created_at": {
            "sec": 1331730738,
            "usec": 810000
        },
{
        "user_name": "john2",
        "role": "user",
        "created_at": {
            "sec": 1331730738,
            "usec": 810000
        },
{
        "user_name": "john3",
        "role": "user",
        "created_at": {
            "sec": 1331730738,
            "usec": 810000
        },
{
        "user_name": "john4",
        "role": "user",
        "created_at": {
            "sec": 1331730738,
            "usec": 810000
        },
    {
        "user_name": "markus",
        "role": "user",
        "created_at": {
            "sec": 1331730738,
            "usec": 810000
        }
]
}
```

i'm trying to create pagination on the page, so i'm trying to select the "members" object that contains array items so i can do sort, skip, limit to paginate.

this is what i have:

```
  var cursor = db.collection("members").find();
    cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
         "use strict";

        if (err) return callback(err, null);

        console.log("Found " + docs[0].members.length + " members");
        console.log(docs[0].members);
        callback(err, docs[0].members);
    });
}
```

how can i select "members"?

i'm very new to this please help
thank you in advance!

Comment: docs doesn't seem to be an array based on your sample give did you try `docs.members.length`, `docs.members[0]` etc

Comment: i used 'docs[0].members' to access the array

Comment: is docs an array? what does `console.log("Found " + docs[0].members.length + " members");` say?

Comment: I don't think you can skip and take on an array in mongo. Also, you may want to consider a separate collection for members with an id back to your current collection.

Comment: @PSL if i do console.log("Found " + docs[0].members.length + " members"); i get: Found 5 members

Comment: @JoshC. should i consider '$unwind'? can you guide me what i'm trying to do?

Comment: How will mongo run the pagination if you use unwind? $Unwind returns the elements of an array as separate documents in a stream. Why not use a separate collection for all members and have an id pointing back to the parent document?

Comment: @JoshC.  i can link a data if i set id on both of the collections right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework to unwind the members array and then skip and limit your result. I just verified it works with a stream of documents which `$unwind` returns.

For your pagination code the command would look like this

`db.members.aggregate([{$unwind : "$members"},{$skip : 1},{$limit: 2}])`

All you need to do now is to customize the parameters for `$skip` and `$limit`

Comment: will i be able to use $sort?

Comment: No but as the aggregation framework returns all results in an array in a document you can sort the resulting array before outputting it. The solution might not be as performant is it would be when you'd sorted the members in MongoDB but this is the only solution I can think of without changing your "schema"

Comment: if i were to change the schema how would you recommend? using separate collection only for member?

Comment: Yes, like the others before me suggested already. It highly depends on your problem domain though but if iterating over the members is something you do often (as it seems) then it makes sense to have the members in a separate collection.

Comment: What do you mean by _link_?

Comment: if i create separate collection only for members, current collection and new collection. link/connect together? like josh mentioned above "a separate collection for all members and have an id pointing back to the parent document"

Comment: Yeah that is possible.

Comment: how do i do that? just set same _id to both data?

Comment: As this is not at all related to the question anymore I recommend you try it yourself first and open a new question in case you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $elemMatch:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/

Try this:

```
db.collection.find({ members: { $elemMatch: { "user_name": "john1" } } });
```